# Dual Problem - Support Vector Machine - Solution by hand

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I am trying to find the solution to the Dual Problem. My data are

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLYnE.png)

with

[image]

I solved it using another method and found

[image]

But I couldn't solve the Dual Problem. Please tell me what I am doing wrong:

#### Method 2: Dual Problem

[image]

So I got that

[image]

Simplifying

[image]

Calculating the partials derivatives:

[image]

So I ended up with this system

[image]

But the solution is a null vector.

Answer (score 1):

Forming the lagrangian

$$
J(\alpha,\lambda) = \sum_k \alpha_k - \frac 12\sum_i\sum_j \alpha_i\alpha_j y_iy_j s_i\cdot s_j+\lambda(\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3)
$$

the stationary conditions are

$$
\nabla J = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 -10 \alpha_1-9 \alpha_2+2 \alpha_3+\lambda +1 \\
 -9 \alpha_1-25 \alpha_2+7 \alpha_3+\lambda +1 \\
 2 \alpha_1+7 \alpha_2-2 \alpha_3-\lambda +1 \\
 \alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

with solution

$$
\alpha_1 = \frac{11}{50},\ \alpha_2 = \frac{3}{25}, \ \alpha_3 = \frac{17}{50}, \ \lambda = \frac 85
$$

Comment: Thanks, Cesareo! I was really stuck with this problem and incredibly I forgot the basic thing... In your answer, I just modified some calculations ... $$\nabla J-\nabla\lambda g=0$$ so the third equation on the system is $$2\alpha_1+7\alpha_2-2\alpha_3+\lambda=-1$$